# @ManyToMany Relationship Between Tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three separate entities `dish, kitchen, restaraunt` and linking table `many`.
My question is, how can I define this relation in my entity classes?

**Kitchen model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kitchen")
public class Kitchen {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_photo")
    private Blob photo;
}
```

**Dish model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dish")
public class Dish {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "dish_name")
    private String dishName;
    @Column(name = "dish_photo")
    private Blob dishPhoto;
```

**Restaraunt model**

```
 public class Restaraunt {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;
        @Column(name = "res_name")
        private String name;
        @Column(name = "res_rating")
        private double rating;
        @Column(name = "res_address")
        private String address;
        @Column(name = "res_number")
        private String number;
        @Column(name = "res_site")
        private String site;
        @Column(name = "res_price")
        private String price;
        @Column(name = "res_photo")
        private Blob photo;
```

Linking table
**Many Model**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "res_id")
    private long res_id;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_id")
    private long kitchen_id;
    @Column(name = "dish_id")
    private long dish_id;
    @Column(name = "many_name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "many_rating")
    private double rating;
    @Column(name = "many_address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "namy_number")
    private String number;
    @Column(name = "many_site")
    private String site;
    @Column(name = "many_price")
    private String price;
    @Column(name = "many_photo")
    private Blob photo;
    @Column(name = "dish_name")
    private String dishName;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_name")
    private String kitchenName;
    @Column(name = "dish_photo")
    private Blob dishPhoto;
    @Column(name = "kitchen_photo")
    private Blob kitchePhoto;
```

I know how to define this relationship between two tables, but for more than two I'm not sure.
Am I need to create table `Many` ?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/) it will help you about association mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by the understanding that a `Restaurant` will have many **dishes** and one `Kitchen`

You can define the relationship like below

```
@Entity
public class Restaraunt {

// all other fields

@OneToMany
private Set<Dish> dishes;

@OneToOne
private Kitchen kitchen;

}
```

You can have the mapping from one side like above or define it from both sides i.e. from `Dish` and `Kitchen` as well - with `Dish` to `Restaurant` as `ManyToOne` and `Kitchen` to `Restaurant` as `OneToOne`

I don't see any reason for having the `Many` model.

Comment: Sry, I didn't mean kitchen, but I meant Food , like Asian Food, Europian etc. But I got your idea, thank you!

Comment: Where is that mentioned in your question? The type of food which you are saying should fall under `Dish`. You can have a field saying `private String dishType` under the `Dish` model and it would serve the purpose. You can have values as Asian, European in `dishType` field.